# Podio PHP: category is empty when no value for item

Tags: php, podio

We are using the Podio PHP library to create forms for our users. These forms load their data from Podio trough the Podio PHP library. A form is linked to a specific Podio Item ID for this.

With this ID we get the fields and their possible values. Most of them are Category fields. We get the values for this trough:

```
<?php

   $item_data = PodioItem::get_basic( $podio_item_id );

   $car_types = $item_data->fields["car-type"]->config['settings']['options'];

   var_dump( $car_types );

?>
```

But the curious thing is, if the item in Podio has no value selected for this category, getting the options fail. It's empty. It doesn't exists.

How do we populate a form with values even if the item has no options selected for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podio doesn't store empty value, it's empty, it doesn't exist, so there is nothing to store. In fact, what you are probably looking for is **Application** definition, which has list fields. Then category field has config with list of possible values and id's and colors.
Like this:

```
"fields": [
      {
      "status": "active",
      "type": "category",
      "field_id": 81772,
      "label": "Status",
      "config": {
        "required": true,
        "label": "Status",
        .....some other config values .....
        "settings": {
          "multiple": false,
          "options": [
            {
              "status": "deleted",         <= example of deleted category option
              "text": "Not groomed",
              "id": 13,
              "color": "DCEBD8"
            },
            {
              "status": "active",          <= example of active category option
              "text": "Open",
              "id": 1,
              "color": "FFD5C2"
            },
            ....                           <= other category options goes here
```

---

You can read more about Apps here: https://developers.podio.com/doc/applications/get-app-22349